# Apache Mod_Rewrite Multiple Levels

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My goal is to make some friendly URL's using .htaccess. I need a mod_rewrite (for .htaccess) solution that allows me to have URLs like:

http://www.example.com/admin/lots -> /admin/lots/index.php

http://www.example.com/admin/lots/edit/1 -> /admin/lots/edit.php?id=1

http://www.example.com/admin/lots/view/1 -> /admin/lots/view.php?id=1

http://www.example.com/admin/lots/view/more/1 -> /admin/lots/view/more.php?id=1

http://www.example.com/admin/settings -> /admin/settings/index.php

http://www.example.com/admin/settings/edit/1 -> /admin/settings/edit.php?id=1

http://www.example.com/admin/project/status/edit/1 -> /admin/project/status/edit.php?id=1

There may be 1 to 10 directory levels with some of the URLs. It's highly unlikely, but if this RewriteCond/Rule could be expandable, that'd be great.

However, the "edit", the "id", and file names may be different. I think that explaining this is very hard to achieve especially because of the hundreds of possibilities.

Basically, I'd like to be shown the file if it exists, and there is nothing else after the file name in the url. If it's a file and has more after the file name, assume it's a variable. If it's a directory with nothing else after it, I'd **prefer** if it could go to the directory index (index.php in this case). If it's a directory with a file name after it, I'd like to be shown that file.

Keep in mind that if a part of the URL is neither a directory or a file, assume it is part of the query, such as `?id=1`

If necessary, I can put it in the server config, however, I'd like to keep it stupid simple.

Comment: Go for one rewrite rule: throw everything that isn't an existing file to a file in the root, and let that file figure out what file to include with what settings with the whole range of PHP functions at your disposal. A lot easier maintainable then swaths of rewrite rules, and a lot easier to code.

Comment: @Wrikken I would have figured that this would be very inefficient. How do large web applications handle these kinds of URLs?

Comment: They do it exactly as I say :P (well, either that, or huge sites just prerender all their pages and just make sure those urls actually exist). Why would it consume _more_ resource for PHP to ask if a file exists then for Apache to ask if a file exist? Especially if you're going to run a php file there anyway, might as well make it an `include` statement at that point. Even if that does not convince you: do you imagine any time spent more doing this in PHP is significant compared to the time the php file you are going to actually run is going to take?

Comment: @Wrikken The problem is that these files actually **do** exist. How would I redirect EVERYTHING in a directory, regardless of existance to a single file? I'm likely overthinking such a simple concept, but I like your approach. And then again, what if the file actually **does not** exist, I know PHP doesn't like displaying custom error pages, unless, of course, you include the ErrorDocument into the central "master" file..

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this URL pattern from Zend Framework. How Zend Framework does it, is rewrite everything to an `index.php`, which bootstraps the application, and does the actual routing according to the routing configuration set in the application.

If this is only in the `/admin/` subdirectory, you could create the following rewrite (based on Zend's default `.htaccess`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [NC,L] # Do not rewrite if it is an actual file/link/directory
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ /admin/router.php [NC,L] # Rewrite to the router.php
```

And in the `router.php`, you can use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to parse the URL, set variables in the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, and include the proper PHP for the given URL, for example.

For the `RewriteCond` usage, check: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Brilliant idea. However, I'm getting a small error with Apache:
`RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters`. There's no line information provided. That's all it says (in terms of useful information).

Comment: Oops. `[NC,L]` should be without a space.

Comment: I apologize for that. I should have caught that first. I'm not a `mod_rewrite` guru. I'll try it out and see how it works.

Comment: Oddly enough, I'm getting 404 errors when I try visiting a nonexistant URL inside the admin directory. It's not forwarding me to the router.php I'm 100% sure that the .htaccess is existing on the server (I tried putting it in both the `/` directory and `/admin/`, I'm also sure that `router.php` exists.

Comment: Well, of course you need:
1. Allow the directory to read the `.htaccess` file with `AllowOverride All` in the Apache/vhost configuration for your project:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

2. Enable `mod_rewrite`, and turn it on for your project (can be done in the `.htaccess` file with `RewriteEngine on`) (I think you already did that, given you had the RewriteRule error)

If this is already the case, you can try turning on logging with `RewriteLog` and see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Found it. Had an extra `/`  in `dmin/.*$ - [NC,L]`. Works when I did `dmin.*$ - [NC,L]`. Does that extra slash need to be there?

Comment: My guts tell me the slash should be there. I'd look in the rewrite log to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Something is wrong with the `^/admin` part. I spoke incorrectly above. I had removed the forward-slash after the carrot, and it worked. Does that slash have any significant effects?

Comment: Ah, that one. Yes I was a bit dubious about that one, whether it had to be included or not. You'll probably also need to remove the first slash in `/admin/router.php` (unless it works like that...). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Do you recommend usage of the slash?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start

Firstly, you'll need to put the following code in a file named .htaccess, in whichever directory you are dealing with:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Now the mod_rewrite module has been turned on, and is ready to accept further instructions. The RewriteRule command is the root of the module, which tells mod_rewrite what to do. Here is its syntax:

RewriteRule Pattern Substitute (Optional Flags)

Here's an example:

```
RewriteRule /articles/([0-9]+) /articles.php?id=$1
```

> This will replace http://www.yoursite.com/articles/1/ with
>   http://www.yoursite.com/articles.php?id=1.

You don't have to limit yourself to numbers either, you can use [a-z] or [A-Z] too!

Here are some flags you can use:

```
f: send a 403 forbidden error to the browser
NC: make the rule case-insensitive
g: send a 410 gone error to the browser
```

Not only can you rewrite URLs using rules, but you can also add conditions to these rules, so they won't be executed in every case:

RewriteCond Test Condition

Here's an example of what you can do with conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Opera.*
RewriteRule ^/$ /index_opera.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Netscape.*
RewriteRule ^/$ /index_netscape.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [L]
```

This will load a special page for Opera and Netscape, and load a default page for people not using Netscape. Here are some variables you can use in your conditions:

```
HTTP_USER_AGENT (browser)
HTTP_REFERER (referring page)
HTTP_HOST (domain name - yoursite.domain.com)
TIME, TIME_YEAR, TIME_DAY, TIME_HOUR, TIME_MIN, TIME_SEC
```

Get to work!

Now that I've (hopefully) wet your appetite, you can get working on some great uses of mod_rewrite. Here are some examples of what can be achieved:

```
/books/456/ » /index.php?mode=books&id=456
/books/456/buy » /index.php?mode=buy&id=456
/book_456.html » /index.php?book=456
```

... and Create beautiful url’s with mod_rewrite

The Apache rewrite engine is mainly used to turn dynamic url’s such as :

> www.yoursite.com/product.php?id=123 into static and user friendly
>   url’s such as www.yoursite.com/product/123

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([^/.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Another example, rewrite from:

> www.yoursite.com/script.php?product=123 to
>   www.yoursite.com/cat/product/123/

```
RewriteRule cat/(.*)/(.*)/$ /script.php?$1=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your **`/admin/.htaccess`**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /admin/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1/index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1/$2.php?id=$3 [L]
```